# VIM textwidth has no effect

Tags: unix, vim, text-editor, neovim

This feels like a dumb question, but I can't find an answer on the Internet (or in VIM help). I'm using VIM 7.2 on Mac OS X. All I want to do is wrap my lines at 72 characters, but doing

```
:set textwidth=72
```

has no effect. The textwidth is being set correctly (I can see that when I just query ":set textwidth"), but neither existing lines nor new lines that I type after setting textwidth get wrapped. If I start a new line, still doesn't wrap. Open and close the file, no change. I've also tried :set wrapmargin=72 (with textwidth=0), with no effect.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 30):

Try `gggqG` to apply the new text width to the whole buffer.

- `gg` means : go to the beginning of buffer
- `gq` means : reformat the text included in the motion
- `G`  means : go to the end of the buffer

(It will work if the format options are correctly set, as detailed in Zyx post)

On the other hand, you could also force your existing text files to a width of 72 characters by adding a `modeline` at the beginning or end of your file. See `:help modeline`.

Something like `vim:tw=72` should work.

Comment: Nice! You made my day.

Answer (score 18):

I was looking for an answer to the same question and had to scramble around a bit before I found the solution in the VIM docs. So, i thought i will update the thread and save others the time.

The problem in my case was that the default ftplugin was disabling textwidth.

Just updating your .vimrc with (`:set tw=79 && :set formatoptions+=t`) won't work since the fplugins are sourced after vimrc.

Here are the steps that i followed:

1) find out what your current formatoptions (inside vim)

```
:set formatoptions?
formatoptions=croql (note no 't')
```

2) create a filetype.vim file as suggested by vimdocs (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#ftplugin-overrule)

```
Overrule the settings after loading the global plugin.
You must create a new filetype plugin in a directory from the end of
'runtimepath'.  For Unix, for example, you could use this file:
    vim ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/fortran.vim
In this file you can change just those settings that you want to change.
```

3) add the line `:set formatoptions+=t` && `:set textwidth=79` in that file.

Voila! next time when you open the file it will set the textwidth to your desired characters.

As a debugging aid you can always check which file is overriding your vimrc setting by prepending your command with verbose. So for e.g. if i want to check who updated the formatoptions last, i would type

```
:verbose set formatoptions? 
formatoptions=croqlt
Last set from ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/fortan.vim
```

Comment: This is the solution to the OPs answer.  The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/513198/xavier-t is the best way to update a file that didn't respect textwidth, but it will do nothing to make the filetype start respecting it.

Answer (score 13):

What does

```
:set formatexpr?
:set indentexpr?
:set cindent?
:set filetype?
:set paste?
:filetype
```

print.

At least one of those (and I think all of them) will override the setting for `textwidth`.

For example, if you're editing a C source file, the C indent rules override `textwidth`.

Comment: Also try `:set paste?`. That one can interfere, too.

Comment: For me it was `:set paste` which I have mapped to a leader sequence. Thank you @patrickvacek

Answer (score 7):

Vim won't do anything unless requested. `textwidth` will have an effect for currently edited lines if you either have `t` (for non-comments only), `c` (for comments only) or both in `formatoptions` (if `a` is not present there, then it will autowrap only when you reach the margin set by `textwidth`), or if you use `gq` to reformat your text. If I am not mistaking, you can set such `formatexpr` or `formatprg` so that `textwidth` will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

```
set formatoptions+=t
```

[This](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_word_wrapping) may help you

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue and found the following solved the issue well enough for me:

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal textwidth=79 formatoptions+=t
```

Feel free to change `python` to be your file type of choice (e.g. `*` or comma separated list `python,ruby,go,sh,javascript`)

> See `:h fo-table` for details of `formatoptions`

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.  The local file type definition overwrites any textwidth values in the .vimrc file, so you need to use this.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Neovim and have met this issue too. After setting `textwidth` to 80 in my `init.vim`, the content of a text file does not change when I open the file. For the existing text, we have to manually format it with `gggqG`.

When you type new characters in a line, the `textwidth` option will work (you will get a linebreak automatically if the character number reaches 80).